# React Native DrawerLayout: shadow on child appears on iOS but not on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I have an app that uses Expo's `GestureHandler.DrawerLayout` with the `"back"` drawer style, such that the view rests atop a stationary drawer and slides off to reveal it. To emphasize this arrangement, I wanted to add a drop shadow to the content `View`, cast on the drawer content. So far, I have this working on iOS but not on Android.

To explore this in isolation from the rest of my app, I've forked the [react-native-gesture-handler](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler) project and modified the `horizontalDrawer` example app. I've added style props for the shadow here:

https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/compare/2542bd39503412ef00883e0e799caf7d1f68ef3a...brettdh:shadows-broken-on-android

As you can see in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qKA2.png), the shadow appears on iOS, but not on Android. However, if I remove absolute positioning by commenting out [this line](https://github.com/brettdh/react-native-gesture-handler/blob/2542bd39503412ef00883e0e799caf7d1f68ef3a/Example/horizontalDrawer/index.js#L98), I see that the shadow is actually being clipped on the left, as you can see in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dR9FF.png).

I've dug into the component tree a bit and tried:

- moving the shadow props to a wrapper `View`
- clearing `overflow: hidden`

  - (though now my understanding is that `overflow: visible` only works on iOS)

I've found discussions describing this as having something to do with absolute positioning, but even if that's the case, I don't think I can avoid that, as it's part of the `DrawerLayout` itself. Any thoughts as to how I can accomplish the same shadow effect on both iOS and Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some further investigation indicates that `DrawerLayout` puts [a `View` around my component](https://github.com/brettdh/react-native-gesture-handler/blob/2542bd39503412ef00883e0e799caf7d1f68ef3a/DrawerLayout.js#L378) that's (probably) clipping the shadow. If I put my `elevation` prop on that `View` instead (along with a `backgroundColor`), the shadow is no longer clipped.

This probably means that I need to make a PR to enable custom styles on this wrapper `View`.

Comment: The aforementioned pull request: https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/pull/163